# How to add radio option in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, adminform

I am trying to add radio option but showing single `radio` without any label

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'test',
            'radio',
            [
                'label' => __('test'),
                'title' => __('test'),
                'name' => 'test',
                'required' => true,
                'values' => array(
                            array('value'=>'1','label'=>'Radio1'),
                            array('value'=>'2','label'=>'Radio2'),
                            array('value'=>'3','label'=>'Radio3'),
                       ),
                'disabled' => $isDisabled
            ]
        );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change type from `radio` to `radios`

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'test',
            'radios',
            [
                'label' => __('test'),
                'title' => __('test'),
                'name' => 'test',
                'required' => true,
                'values' => array(
                            array('value'=>'1','label'=>'Radio1'),
                            array('value'=>'2','label'=>'Radio2'),
                            array('value'=>'3','label'=>'Radio3'),
                       ),
                'disabled' => $isDisabled
            ]
        );
```

for more types you can look in to `namespace Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element`

Comment: How to make first option as selected?

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'test',
            'radios',
            [
                'name' => 'test',
                'label' => __('Radio'),
                'title' => __('Radio'),
                'required' => true,
                'values' => [
                                ['value' =>1, 'label' => __('Yes')],
                                ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('No')]
                            ],
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );
```

[image]

Comment: could you guide me to get all radios in single row as all my radios are taking 1 row each

Comment: Use above code which i have added in answer

Comment: It will display only two option in one row if options are more than 2 it will not display in single row

Comment: @PrashantValanda you code is not matching with your output image

Comment: It is same as image only label is changed because while i capturing snap at that time label is other. :)

Comment: @PrashantValanda if values are more than two then its not coming in one row

Comment: @MohammadMujassam Yes i have mentioned in previous comment

Comment: @PrashantValanda actually I have two select box that I want in one row, have any idea ??

Comment: @MohammadMujassam Can you please add a new question with your code.

Comment: @PrashantValanda this is the link of my  [question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113920/magento2-how-place-2-3-form-fields-in-one-row-in-admin-edit-form)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the way Magento 2 handles radio require multiple radio fields with the same name.

There's a good example in `app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/AttributeSet/Form.php`

In your case the right code would be:

```
    $fieldset->addField(
        'Radio1',
        'radio',
        [
            'name' => 'test',
            'value' => '1'
        ]
    );
    $fieldset->addField(
        'Radio2',
        'radio',
        [
            'name' => 'test',
            'value' => '2'
        ]
    );
    $fieldset->addField(
        'Radio3',
        'radio',
        [
            'name' => 'test',
            'value' => '3'
        ]
    );
```

On top of that it seems like `app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Helper/Form/Weight.php` uses a slightly different method in the below code but as it is a custom element I'm not sure if that will fit your needs:

```
    $this->weightSwitcher = $factoryElement->create('radios');
    $this->weightSwitcher->setValue(
        WeightResolver::HAS_WEIGHT
    )->setValues(
        [
            ['value' => WeightResolver::HAS_WEIGHT, 'label' => __('Yes')],
            ['value' => WeightResolver::HAS_NO_WEIGHT, 'label' => __('No')]
        ]
    )->setId(
        'weight-switcher'
    )->setName(
        'product_has_weight'
    )->setLabel(
        __('Does this have a weight?')
    );
```