# magento2: how place 2-3 form fields in one row in admin edit form

Tags: magento-2.0, adminform

I want to add multiple form fields in single row in admin edit form, My question is same as in the link [here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111074/magento2-how-to-add-multiple-fields-in-single-row-in-magento-edit-form)(however I only asked this question)